# Teradata conditional expand

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with dates and val that I trying to expand and fill in missing dates in order. Not shown is that I am doing this by group and location, but the crux of what I need to do is below. Say I have the following table

```
dt | val
2014-01-01 | 10
2014-02-17  | 9 
2014-04-21  | 5
```

I have expanded to this is a week table filling in missing with zeros

```
week_bgn_dt| week_end_dt|  val
2014-01-01 | 2014-01-08 |  10
2014-01-09 | 2014-01-16 |  0
2014-01-17 | 2014-01-24 |  0
...
2014-02-10 | 2014-02-17 |  0
2014-02-18 | 2014-02-25 |  9
2014-02-26 | 2014-03-05 |  0
2014-03-06 | 2014-03-13 |  0
...
2014-03-30 | 2014-04-06 |  0
2014-04-07 | 2014-04-14 |  0
2014-04-15 | 2014-04-22 |  5
```

what I want is fill in with the last value until a change, so the output would looks like

```
week_bgn_dt| week_end_dt|  val
2014-01-01 | 2014-01-08 |  10
2014-01-09 | 2014-01-16 |  10
2014-01-17 | 2014-01-24 |  10
...
2014-02-10 | 2014-02-17 |  10
2014-02-18 | 2014-02-25 |  9
2014-02-26 | 2014-03-05 |  9
2014-03-06 | 2014-03-13 |  9
...
2014-03-30 | 2014-04-06 |  9
2014-04-07 | 2014-04-14 |  9
2014-04-15 | 2014-04-22 |  5
```

In teradata I have tried this

```
case when val <> 0 then val 
   else sum(val) over (partition by group, location order by group, store, week_bgn_dt 1 preceding  to current row) as val2
```

but this only give the last value once, like so,

```
week_bgn_dt| week_end_dt|  val | val2
2014-01-01 | 2014-01-08 |  10  | 10
2014-01-09 | 2014-01-16 |  0   | 10
2014-01-17 | 2014-01-24 |  0   | 0
...
2014-02-10 | 2014-02-17 |  0   | 0 
2014-02-18 | 2014-02-25 |  9   | 9
2014-02-26 | 2014-03-05 |  0   | 9
2014-03-06 | 2014-03-13 |  0   | 0
...
2014-03-30 | 2014-04-06 |  0   | 0
2014-04-07 | 2014-04-14 |  0   | 0
2014-04-15 | 2014-04-22 |  5   | 5
```

If I make the window unbounded, it sums when I hit a new value

```
case when val <> 0 then val 
   else sum(val) over (partition by group, location order by group, store, week_bgn_dt unbounded preceding  to current row) as val2

week_bgn_dt| week_end_dt|  val | val2
2014-01-01 | 2014-01-08 |  10  | 10
2014-01-09 | 2014-01-16 |  0   | 10
2014-01-17 | 2014-01-24 |  0   | 10
...
2014-02-10 | 2014-02-17 |  0   | 10 
2014-02-18 | 2014-02-25 |  9   | 9
2014-02-26 | 2014-03-05 |  0   | 19
2014-03-06 | 2014-03-13 |  0   | 19
...
2014-03-30 | 2014-04-06 |  0   | 19
2014-04-07 | 2014-04-14 |  0   | 19
2014-04-15 | 2014-04-22 |  5   | 5
```

I have tried with max() and min(), but to similar results. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: How is your week defined? Based on your example it seems to be 8 days? Are those weeks always based on 8 days and how do they relate to val?

Comment: And what's your TD release? In TD13 there's RESET WHEN, but EXPAND ON in TD13.10 might be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the partitioning in the `SUM` operation. Remember that when `OVER` clause is specified, `SUM` calculates its results for each partition separately starting from zero for each partition. It appears that you want `SUM` to function over multiple partitions. As we cannot tell `SUM` in any way (that I'm aware of) to operate over multiple partitions, the way around is to redefine the partitioning to something else.

I your case, it appears that `SUM` should not use partitions at all. All we need are the `RESET WHEN` feature and the windowing operation of `OVER`. Using your expanded results filled with zeros, I have achieved the required output with following query.

```
SELECT 
    week_bgn_dt,
    week_end_dt,
    val,
    SUM(val) OVER ( PARTITION BY 1
                    ORDER BY location ASC, week_bgn_dt ASC
                    RESET WHEN val<>0
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS val2
FROM test

week_bgn_dt | week_end_dt | val | val2
2014-01-01  | 2014-01-08  |  10 |  10
2014-01-09  | 2014-01-16  |  0  |  10
2014-01-17  | 2014-01-24  |  0  |  10
2014-02-10  | 2014-02-17  |  0  |  10
2014-02-18  | 2014-02-25  |  9  |  9
2014-02-26  | 2014-03-05  |  0  |  9
2014-03-06  | 2014-03-13  |  0  |  9
2014-03-30  | 2014-04-06  |  0  |  9
2014-04-07  | 2014-04-14  |  0  |  9
2014-04-15  | 2014-04-22  |  5  |  5
```

You might have noticed that I have added only location to the provided data. I believe you can add rest of the fields to `ORDER BY` clause and get the right results.